# Vertical wind measurements

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerodynamics

How can the vertical wind direction be measured?

For a project I have to design a wind turbine and I would like the blades to make slight adjustments based on the wind direction in order to achieve the most efficient energy conversion. Whilst I can use a wind vane to get the direction of the wind on a horizontal plane; I have been unable to find a method for finding the direction of the wind on a vertical plane.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: To what budget?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Anything under £3,000,000 ($3,700,000 USD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the budget of up to £3m, then lidar scanning seems to be current state of the art for 3-d profiling of wind for active management of wind turbines.

Here's a [sample business case](http://www.dewi.de/dewi_res/fileadmin/pdf/publications/Magazin_37/08.pdf) for one.

The WINDCUBE v2 is a vertical wind profiler that uses doppler pulsed lidar. [Here's a presentation on it](http://www.norcowe.no/doc/Documents%20for%20web/SMI%20S%20Presentasjonar/E%20Santiago,%20A.,%20Leosphere.pdf).

As far as I know, lidar has mostly been used in offshore wind. There are quite a few academic papers on its use in the wind industry. I don't know what, if anything, has been done about processing vertical-plane wind data, but there's an increasing number of conference= and journal- papers on yield optimisation for wind turbines, so there could be quite a bit of existing literature in the field on this already.